# Safari browsers - select dropdown not showing default option, only first option from ngFor

Tags: html, css, angular, drop-down-menu, safari

I am currently having an issue with one of my select dropdown boxes not showing as I expect, just within Safari browsers / on some Mac IOS devices.

I expect the dropdown to show "Select country" in the field & in the dropdown, prompting the user to select a country. However instead "United Kingdom" shows first in the field, which is the first option in the first ngFor but "Select country" shows first in the dropdown list (greyed out).

I have tried adding / removing the "Select country" text. I'm not sure if changing the value of value would help or possibly adding a style property.

I am testing on BrowserStack and using Angular 10.

HTML template

```
<div class="mb-4">
    <label class="block text-sm text-gray-600 text-md font-medium mb-1">Country *</label>
    <div class="relative">
        <select name="country"
                class="form-control custom-select block sm:text-sm appearance-none text-gray-600 w-full bg-white border border-gray-300 hover:border-gray-500 px-3 py-2 pr-8 rounded-md shadow-sm leading-tight focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500"
                formControlName="country"
                [class.border-red-500]="country.invalid && country.touched"
                autocomplete="off"
                required>
            <option [value]="null" selected disabled hidden>Select country</option>
            <option *ngFor="let country of popularCountries" [value]="country.id">
                {{ country.name }}
            </option>
            <option *ngFor="let country of otherCountries" [value]="country.id">
                {{ country.name }}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

TS Component

```
this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
    country: ['', Validators.required],
        });

this.popularCountries = this.countries.filter(f => f.name === "United Kingdom" || f.name === "United States");
this.otherCountries = this.countries.filter(f => f.name !== "United Kingdom" && f.name !== "United States");
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you reproduce it in a stackblitz? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-91nhqu

Comment: so how does it look in safari? can you provide a screenshot? because in your linked screenshot the "Select Country" is actually visible

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input eko and Nicolas. I changed the empty string, '' in the formBuilder to Null and this fixed the issue. Not entirely happy as the template code should have worked as it's worked elsewhere in my programme.

```
this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
    country: [Null, Validators.required],
        });
```